# Raspberry PI import tensorflow Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have installed tensorflow on a Raspberry PI 3 and it worked correctly (following these [instructions](https://hackaday.com/2018/05/18/five-steps-to-tensorflow-on-the-raspberry-pi/)). After installing a number of libraries that I needed for loading a Keras model trained on my PC (numpy, scipy etc) I have observed the following error while importing tensorflow:

```
Runtime Error: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
Segmentation fault
```

I have updated all the necessary libraries, and importing any of them doesn't result in an error in a Python 3 script. Also the error is not keras related, because the statement `import tensorflow` raises an error no matter what follows after it. Should I uninstall tensorflow and start all over again?

Comment: Compile tensorflow again.

Comment: @ Ipor Sircer: I've tried ./configure and bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package but after doing that the problem persists.